# How do I port an Arduino C++ library to an STM32CubeIDE C library?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, stm32, stm32cubeide

The library in question is the Adafruit VL6180X TOF sensor (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_VL6180X). I am using the Nucleo L432KC development board. I believe i have successfully ported the both header files but I am having trouble with the source file for the VL6180X sensor. I don't have much knowledge in C++ and even less in translating it to C. I am looking for possible solutions/guidance in tackling this.

Ported header for VL6180X:

```
#ifndef ADAFRUIT_VL6180X_H
#define ADAFRUIT_VL6180X_H

#include "Adafruit_I2CDevice.h"
#include "main.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define VL6180X_DEFAULT_I2C_ADDR 0x29

#define VL6180X_ERROR_NONE 0
#define VL6180X_ERROR_SYSERR_1 1
#define VL6180X_ERROR_SYSERR_5 5
#define VL6180X_ERROR_ECEFAIL 6
#define VL6180X_ERROR_NOCONVERGE 7
#define VL6180X_ERROR_RANGEIGNORE 8
#define VL6180X_ERROR_SNR 11
#define VL6180X_ERROR_RAWUFLOW 12
#define VL6180X_ERROR_RAWOFLOW 13
#define VL6180X_ERROR_RANGEUFLOW 14
#define VL6180X_ERROR_RANGEOFLOW 15

#define VL6180X_DEFAULT_I2C_ADDR 0x29

typedef struct Adafruit_VL6180X_s {
    I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c;
    uint8_t i2caddr;
} Adafruit_VL6180X;

HAL_StatusTypeDef Adafruit_VL6180X_begin(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x, I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c);

HAL_StatusTypeDef Adafruit_VL6180X_setAddress(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x, uint8_t newAddr);

uint8_t Adafruit_VL6180X_getAddress(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x);

uint8_t Adafruit_VL6180X_readRange(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x);

uint8_t Adafruit_VL6180X_readRangeStatus(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x);

HAL_StatusTypeDef Adafruit_VL6180X_startRange(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x);

bool Adafruit_VL6180X_isRangeComplete(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x);

bool Adafruit_VL6180X_waitRangeComplete(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x);

uint8_t Adafruit_VL6180X_readRangeResult(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x);

void Adafruit_VL6180X_startRangeContinuous(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x, uint16_t period_ms);

void Adafruit_VL6180X_stopRangeContinuous(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x);

void Adafruit_VL6180X_setOffset(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x, uint8_t offset);

void Adafruit_VL6180X_getID(Adafruit_VL6180X *vl6180x, uint8_t *id_ptr);

#endif
```

Ported Header for I2C communication:

```
#ifndef Adafruit_I2CDevice_h
#define Adafruit_I2CDevice_h

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
  uint8_t _addr;
  void* _wire;
  bool _begun;
  size_t _maxBufferSize;
} Adafruit_I2CDevice;

void Adafruit_I2CDevice_begin(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device, bool addr_detect);
uint8_t Adafruit_I2CDevice_address(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device);
void Adafruit_I2CDevice_end(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device);
bool Adafruit_I2CDevice_detected(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device);
bool Adafruit_I2CDevice_read(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device, uint8_t *buffer, size_t len, bool stop);
bool Adafruit_I2CDevice_write(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device, const uint8_t *buffer, size_t len, bool stop,
             const uint8_t *prefix_buffer, size_t prefix_len);
bool Adafruit_I2CDevice_write_then_read(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device, const uint8_t *write_buffer, size_t write_len,
                       uint8_t *read_buffer, size_t read_len, bool stop);
bool Adafruit_I2CDevice_setSpeed(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device, uint32_t desiredclk);
size_t Adafruit_I2CDevice_maxBufferSize(Adafruit_I2CDevice* device);

#endif
```

Comment: I think you are in the right track. For the `.cpp` file, just keep renaming the member functions as you did in the header, in a `.c` file. Define the member variables (`i2c_dev`, `_i2c` and `_i2caddr`) there at the top of this `.c` file.

Comment: Can you please explain "having trouble" more? what happens? Also, have you made the MCU configurations as well? This is sth that is not required in Arduino but very important in CubeIDE.